# Problems with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a small server where when the client logs in gets some messages.

**The server code**

```
import socket

#Networking
s = socket.socket()

print("Network successfully created")

port = 3642


s.bind(('',port))

print("Network has been binded to %s" %(port))

s.listen(5)

print("Waiting for connections")


while True:

    c, addr = s.accept()

    print("Got a connection from",addr)


    c.send(bytes("Thank you for connecting to me. Currently we","utf-8"))
    c.send(bytes("Working on the server","utf-8"))

c.close()
```

**This is the client code**

```
# Import socket module
import socket               

# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket()         

# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 3642                

# connect to the server on local computer
s.connect(('MyIp..', port))

# receive data from the server
print(s.recv(1024))
# close the connection
s.close()
```

Everything works fine such as the connecting and the first message gets printed, however I can't get the second message to get printed. The one that says working on the server. I have just began learning about sockets and barely know anything about them so the solution probably is obvious it's just 
I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you for any responses. (I would appreciate thorough responses)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. But note that with TCP, message boundaries are not respected. Hence, both buffers you `send` will (or at least may) get consolidated into a single `recv` buffer (that's what I'm seeing). Other notes: (a) This is not valid python-3.x (on client-side, due to missing parentheses in the print statement); (b) You should put the `c.close()` inside the loop on the server side -- otherwise you're leaving all previously-accepted connections open until the program exits.

Comment: For a I printed it wrong sorry, I edited it now. 2nd I did put c.close() inside the loop. That doesnt do it either. I only see the first statement thats printed from the server but not the second one.

Comment: The very same code you pasted works perfectly fine locally (using '127.0.0.1' or the IP address of the machine on the local network as 'MyIP').

Comment: If the two sent buffers happen to *not* get consolidated into a single buffer in the `recv` (which can happen based on timing, which OS you're running and other factors), then it makes sense that you would not see the second buffer because you're only making one `recv` call. If you want to receive everything the server sent, put the `recv` in a loop until it returns an empty string. (Empty string indicates end-of-file [i.e. socket closed by the other end].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two sent buffers happen to not get consolidated into a single buffer in the `recv` (which can happen based on timing, which OS you're running and other factors), then it makes sense that you would not see the second buffer because you're only making one `recv` call. If you want to receive everything the server sent, put the `recv` in a loop until it returns an empty string. (Empty string indicates end-of-file [i.e. socket closed by the other end].) – Gil Hamilton